# Trigonometric fit in Mathematica not working?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, trigonometry, curve-fitting

I am trying to curve fit some periodical experimental data, and discovered that the methods that work for curve-fitting to other functions do not work for trigonometric ones--at least--the way I am doing it.

Here is my code:

```
falseData = Table[{x, N[3*Sin[4*x]]}, {x, 10}];
model = a*Sin[b*x];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[falseData, model, {a, b}, x]
Show[ListPlot[falseData, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[fit[x], {x, 1, 10}]]
```

And here is what the code generates:

```
FittedModel[-0.184706 Sin[1.00073 x]]
```

[image: A failure of a curve fit]

It works perfectly if I switch the Sin functions in this example to Log or to another type of function, but it fails when I try to use Sin or Cos.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This problem was substantially covered on [mathematica.se] by this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2327/52).

Comment: @rcollyer Please remember that the Mma site is still in beta ...

Comment: Thank you rcollyer. I didn't find that link with the Google keywords I was using...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using NMinimize method:

```
falseData = Table[{x, N[3*Sin[4*x]]}, {x, 10}];
model = a*Sin[b*x];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[falseData, model, {a, b}, x, Method -> NMinimize]
Show[ListPlot[falseData, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[fit[x], {x, 1, 10}]]
```

Here is the output:

```
FittedModel[-3. Sin[2.28319 x]]
```

And here is the resulting curve:

[image: result of fitting]